# Android のバージョンタグは必要か

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグwiki

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

の、タグ Wiki を見ていました。各バージョンごとのタグがここで定義されていますが、そのすべてのタグを見ましたが質問がひとつもひもづいていません。

このバージョンタグはそもそも必要なのでしょうか。

---

文脈が多少必要になるかと思うので追記。

レビューの中で、当該タグWiki に対しての編集提案が回ってきました。何かというと、 `android-6.0` を追加するものでした。しかし、そもそもひもづいている質問がないのに、 Wiki の中でだけタグを整理していくのは、どうなんでしたっけ？編集もレビューも（微々たるものかもしれないが) コストはかかるので、そのコストに対して、意味があるのか？と思ってこの投稿をした次第です。

Comment: 現状バージョンタグにする必要がないのであれば、紛らわしいので全部削ってしまった方がいいと思います。ただ、一般論としてのバージョンタグの是非もそうですが、android関連の質問に回答されている方々がどう思われるか気になるところです。

Comment: @unarist タグを作成するのならば、少なくとも一つのそれにひもづく質問があるべきだと思っています。（イメージなんですが、タグの定義は実際に作成された質問たちの分類をもとに、帰納的に定義されるのが正しいと感じています。あらかじめタグを作成しておくのは演繹的というか、そんな感じがしていて、タグというシステムがそれでうまく機能するイメージがあまりわかないです)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今日編集依頼をした者ですが、不要だと思います。
タグwikiは **情報や使い方** についてを書くところで誰も使っていないタグを掲載する必要はないと考えています。

---

ちなみに、編集した理由はandroidのバージョンタグがたくさんある中、6.0が無いなと思い編集しました。