# Androidのバージョンタグが質問に紐付いていますが必要でしょうか

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, タグ

少々気になったので質問させて頂きます。
前に`android-(バージョン)`のようなタグが[タグwiki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)に書かれていて本当に必要なのか[議論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/android-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AF%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81%E3%81%8B/)された末、[削除](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/244/4)されました。

私が気になったのは[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28795/google-maps%E3%81%AE%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%B0%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)のタグなのですが、`android-6.0-marshmallow`というタグは必要でしょうか？

Comment: 参考程度に [タグを作成する基準はありますか](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2007/15185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以前の議論の結論に賛成です。
現在のこのサイトの状況からすると、以下2点が予想されるためです。

- あまりタグを増やすと該当する質問が極端に少なくなる
- タグのメンテの負担に耐え切れなく放置される

---

ただ、私はあまり Android の事情が分かっていないので、強く主張するつもりはありません。
Android 関連では、`android-studio`のタグも気になっています。
大抵の質問に`android-studio`が付いている印象なのですが、そういう物なのですかね。

Comment: そうですね。`android-studio`については自分も気になっています。自分が見かけたら削除します。ただ、回答が集まりにくくなるかなと思うので極力関係あるタグがあれば置き換えるようにしています。