# バージョンタグは必要か

Tags: 討議, タグ

[Android のバージョンタグは必要か](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2208/4236)という議論もありましたが、一般化してバージョンタグが必要なのか気になっています。SOjaは質問数もそれほど多くなく、バージョンごとにタグ分けする意義があるのか（バージョンタグで検索してもろくな結果が得られないのでは）、という点です。
弊害の例として

- [Widows10 ページングファイル設定の異常](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91578/4236)
  Windows全般に適用されそうな話題だが、windows-10タグのみが付けられ、逆にwindowsタグが付けられていない。
- [7zipのシェルコンテキストメニューに7zipを登録ができない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91618/4236)
  Windows 11の質問にもかかわらず、windows-10タグが付けられていた（[リビジョン１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/91618/1)）

もちろん、気づいた人が編集すればいいのですが、バージョンタグに意義がないならいっそ廃止してしまった方がいいのではと考えています。

全てにおいて不要とは言えないかもしれませんが、一定の指針なりがあってもいいのではと。

- [タグの人気順一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular)

  - 現時点でpythonタグが1位でpython3タグ6位ですね。今はpython=python3.xでしょうから、質問を精査するとpythonタグのほぼすべてにpython3タグも付けられて2位になってしまわないかと。
  - 例に挙げたwindowsは20位で、これをバージョン分けしても…。

Answer (score 5):

日本語版 `ja.stackoverflow.com` 限定の話として

言語仕様バージョンはあってもよいのかも (C89 とか C#5 とか) と思ったのですが、でも現状 c11 タグはあっても c89 c99 は無いし c# に至っては誰も言語仕様バージョンを意識していないのかバージョン付きタグは一切ありません。 fortran も同様です。

そういう現状なので、今すぐあわてて追加なり削除なりする必然はなく、よってゆるく放置プレイしておけば十分なのではないかな、とか思ったりします。逆に今すぐ強権発動して削除してしまっても誰も困らないのかもしれません。

# 英語版には C#-5.0 みたいに細分タグがある模様

Answer (score 4):

Python まわりでよくバージョン付きのタグを触るので、まず Python に特化した話を書いてみます。Python については、バージョン付きのタグで自分はたすかっています。

Python まわりではバージョンなしのタグとバージョンありのタグをどちらも使っていて、たとえば [python3](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3) は [python](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) と併用してほしいとタグ wiki 抜粋に書かれています: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/python3/info

この記述は僕が SOja に参加するより前から書かれていて、いままで自分はこの記述にしたがって [python3](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3) しか付けられていない質問に [python](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) を付けてまわっていたりしました。

この運用は英語版 Stack Overflow でも同様です: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info

個人的には、今のこの運用にそこまで不便を感じていません。将来的に Python 4 が出たら [python3](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3) が付いている質問は古いかもしれないと判断できるでしょうし、未だに投稿される Python 2 の質問を [python2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2) で分類できるのは、回答者としても目の前の問題の解決法を探す人としても嬉しいです。それくらい、Python 2 と 3 で解決方法が異なることがザラにあるので……。

Python 以外に目を向けると、たとえば Ubuntu の質問に対して [ubuntu-22.04](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-22.04) みたくバージョンごとにタグを作っても細かくなりすぎてしまって、今の SOja の質問流量だとそこまで便利ではないだろうなと思います。全部 [ubuntu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) にしつつ質問文にバージョンを書くくらいで良いでしょう。Ubuntu のバージョンアップ頻度が遅すぎず互換性の維持がそれなりになされるために、他バージョンでの知見が今困っている問題の解決に役に立つことがよくあるので、バージョンごとにタグを区切ってもあまり使わないということなのかもしれません。（ちなみに、superuser.com だと Ubuntu のバージョンごとのタグがありますがあんまり利用されていませんでした。）

Windows 系のタグにバージョンごとのタグが必要かどうかはちょっと判断に悩みますね。実際に質問したり回答したり Q&A を探したりしている人のご意見を聞いてみたいです。

総論として「不便だったら、消そう」くらいのことは言えるかもしれませんがなにか指標を作って一括で判断するのは難しく、分野ごとに各論を考えてメタで議論して作ったり消したりするくらいで良いかなあと思いました。無茶苦茶不便で検索の体験を凄く損なっているということであれば客観的かつ量的な判断基準を設ける価値がありそうですが、現状そこまでやるほどの価値はなく、ゆるく運用していくぐらいで大丈夫だろうと個人的には考えています。

Answer (score 3):

メジャーバージョンぐらいにはバージョンタグがあっても良いと思います。

Windowsについて言うと、XP,Vista,7,8,10と移り変わるときにOS周りの動作に色々と変更とがあったと思います。Windowsは可能な限り互換性を保つようにしていますが、前バージョンでは動いていたのに、新しいバージョンでは動かないということはそれほど珍しくありません。特に、OSが管理している動作(スタートメニューやシェルコンテキストメニュー等)はバージョンによって動く動かないはよくあることかと思います。

例えば、「PowerShellで、タスクバーのスタートメニューボタンを左端に表示するよう設定するようにしたい」という質問が`windows`のタグのみであったとき、Widows 10を持っているけどWindows 11を持っていないユーザーがみてもちんぷんかんぷんです。そういうときは、`windows-11`タグを付けてあってもいいんじゃ無いかなと思っています。

だからといってWindows 11なら何でもという事ではないかなとも思っています。Windows 11に依存しないとわかれば`windows-11`を付け続けるのはある意味弊害です。その時はタグを外してあえげればいいのでは無いかと思っています。

他にもWindowsは8と8.1は結構違うとか、10もFeature Updateによって違うとか、10と11は結構似ているとか、細かい話はあるかも知れません。ただ、こういう物は、原則最新にできるし、ほとんどの人は最新状態での問題発生の解決に興味があると考えられます。なので、普通にアップデートができない範囲毎がちょうどいいと思います。そういう意味では、macOSは(古い機種出ない限り)メジャーバージョンをあげていけるので、分ける必要は無いのでは無いかという感じです(むしろ、macOSはx64とARM64で分ける必要があるかも知れませんが)。あとはJavaのように毎年メジャーバージョンが出る場合ですが、実際の所、LTSバージョン以外は利用者ほごく少数なので、1年ほどしかサポートされないバージョンはスキップして、LTSだけに限定しても良いとも追います。

逆の反論として、Windows 10とWindows 11はそれほど変わらないのでは？という人もいるかも知れません。スタートメニューの件も含めて設定項目は結構変わっています。違いが多い少ないだと主観によるので、別の方法で線引きをすべきです。私としては、「ほとんどの人がアップデートできるかどうか」かと思います。ハードの制限でWindows 10をWindows 11にアップデートできないと言うことがかなりの数である限り、分けて考えるべきかと思います。

指針としてはこんな感じがいいのでは無いでしょうか？

- メジャーバージョンのタグはありとする。

  - ただし、シームレスにアップデートしていくことが可能な場合は無し。(macOSとか)
  - 毎年メジャーバージョンアップするような場合は、LTSバージョンだけを対象とする。(Javaなら8,11,17のみとか)
- そのバージョン特有で有ることがわかっていれば、付ける。

  - そのバージョン特有の機能である(先程のスタートメニューボタンの位置とか)
  - バージョンの違い大きくて、たぶん動かない(Pythonの2と3みたいなもの)
- そのバージョン特有かどうか確実に判断できない場合、どちらでも良い。

  - 特有でありそうなら、付けても良い。

    - そのバージョン特有では無い(他でも起きる)と判明すれば、外す。
  - 逆に、特有ではなさそうなら、付けなくても良い。

    - 後から、そのバージョン特有と判明すれば、付ける。

そう考えると、「7zipのシェルコンテキストメニューに7zipを登録ができない」では、`windows-11`と付けるかどうかは微妙なところですが、のちほど質問者がWindows 10でも現象を確認しているとあるので、外すべきなので、外しとおきます。